# HLSL: How to transform vertex to screen space just like the rasterizer, but with subpixel accuracy?

Tags: c++, hlsl, direct3d11, rasterizing

I want to draw a point-list using vertex- and pixelshader. Each point's rendered color should represent its subpixel accurate screen-space coordinate (outputting to R32G32_FLOAT texture).
I do the following in my VS:

```
struct VSOutput
{
    float4 position : SV_Position;
    float2 screenSpacePosition : COLOR;
};

VSOutput VS(uint index : SV_VertexID)
{
    float3 pointPos = inPointPositions[index];
    VSOutput output;
    output.position = mul(transform, float4(pointPos, 1));
    output.screenSpacePosition = (float2(+1, -1) * output.position.xy / output.position.w * 0.5f + 0.5f) * float2(width, height);
    return output;
}
```

In my PS I'd normally just use the screenSpacePosition field as my final target color, but since I experienced some issues I changed it to verify that the computed screenSpacePosition coincides with the actual pixel-position used for rasterization (to debug the issue). It will output a WHITE color if the computed screenSpacePosition matches the rasterized position, and RED otherwise.

```
float4 PS(VSOutput input) : SV_Target
{
    return all(floor(output.screenSpacePosition) == floor(input.position.xy)) ? float4(1, 1, 1, 1) : float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Now allmost all pixels are white as is to be expected, but there is occasional red noise on top. I strongly assume the reason for this is that the rasterizer uses an internal 16.8 fixed-point format for mapping to actual pixels, such that mappings don't agreee 100% between that fixed-point format and my float transformation.
Is there any way to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ceil()` instead of `floor()`.

Consider the point rasterization rule,
[Point Rasterization Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCfGD.png)

Say if a screen space pos outputed by VS happens to be exactly at integer pixel coord `(n, m)`, the pixel centered at `(n - 0.5, m - .5)` will be rasterized and receives the SV_POSITION `(n - 0.5, m - 0.5)` in PS, while the manually calculated pos that passed to PS still be `(n, m)`, which will return different value after applying `floor()`